Permanently configure Wine to respect my screen rotation
I have a laptop that can be folded "backwards" and turned upside down to basically use it as a monitor with an external mouse and keyboard. Since the laptop is upside down, I have to rotate my screen in software, which Ubuntu conveniently has a feature for. But if I try to launch a game in Wine like this, it sometimes launches the game upside down.
This happens mostly with older games, my guess is it only happens when the game requires a resolution change because it's low resolution. Is there a way I can set launch options for these games to have them use the current orientation of the screen? Is there a way I can tell Wine to always do that?
